# Pass audio file to Assistant SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to pass an audio file to Google Assistant SDK using Node.js, specifically this lib: https://github.com/endoplasmic

My audio file is a wav with the following format:

```
{ audioFormat: 1,
  endianness: 'LE',
  channels: 1,
  sampleRate: 24000,
  byteRate: 48000,
  blockAlign: 2,
  bitDepth: 16,
  signed: true }
```

What I am  trying to do is create a readFile of the wav file and write it to the assistant conversation like so:

```
fs.readFile(`${path.resolve(__dirname, 'response.wav')}`, (err, file) => {
  if(err) console.log(err)
  assistant.start(global.config.conversation, (conversation) => {
    conversation.write(file)
     return self.startConversation(conversation)
     .then((data) => {
       console.log(data)
       //resolve(data)
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err)
       //reject(err)
     })
   });
```

The problem I have though is that it nothing happens. 
If even trying

```
.on('end-of-utterance', () => {
  console.log("Done speaking")
})
.on('transcription', (data) => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

But nothing logs here either.  Eventually it logs an error:

> Error: Service unavailable.
>       at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/Users/Greg/Documents/Projects/st-gassist/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:255:19)
>       at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (/Users/Greg/Documents/Projects/st-gassist/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:233:8)
>       at /Users/Greg/Documents/Projects/st-gassist/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:757:12
>   code: 14, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} }

Does anyone know how I can go about passing this audio file?  I want to pass an audio file as it is a pre-recorded message, an alternative to recording the mic

Comment: What is the type of `file`? You should be sending the audio data as a int array.

Comment: @NickFelker I've updated my question to reflect your comment

Comment: Would you be able to just send text instead?

Comment: I'm already doing that for something else successfully.  For this though, I need to do it via audio unfortunately.